# What filesystem for an external Harddrive (Linux/Mac/Windows)

Tags: windows, filesystem, mac, compatibility

What Filesystem should I use for an external USB harddrive (500GB), with possibility 
to share with a Mac and Windows systems, for example at the office.
Now it is NTFS but back in the day the NTFS support was not stable under Linux and I think it is not supported on a Mac.

I would just use FAT32, but it has 4GB file size limitation, do I overlooked any other option?

I looked here: [filesystem types for partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19796/filesystem-types-for-partitions) but a Mac is not mentioned.

*edit* Windows is the least important, I am not sure if I need Windows support at all.
So what would I use just for Linux and Mac?

*edit* I am not so happy with the performance, I don't know if the problem lie in NTFS USB or whatever, but the process mount.ntfs has a high CPU usage while copying. I just get <10MByte/s writing

Comment: UDF works great if you use the right options, check: http://serverfault.com/questions/55089/with-what-tool-should-i-format-a-hard-drive-as-udf

Comment: See also this page: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59585/file-system-compatible-with-all-oses

Comment: See also: [Unix & Linux: File system compatible with all OSes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59585/114401). In [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/746786/114401), I recommend exFAT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually i just go with NTFS. It's way better than FAT32, and it's relatively easy to install NTFS-compatibility on both Mac and Linux (compared to installing filesystems on Windows).

For Mac you need either the free [NTFS-3g](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/ntfs3g.html) or the commercial version of the same, [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/). These are only needed if you want to be able to write to the disk. OSX can read NTFS.

For Linux, it's also NTFS-3g. To install it on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.

Comment: I second Fraekkert, but I think that switching to a network drive would save you from these problems.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 (and i think 10.04 also does...) comes with ntfs-3g already, like OSX it can out-of-the-box read NTFS yet you need ntfs-config from USC to write to the NTFS disk

Comment: I also second Fraekkert.
Both Ubuntu and OSX comes with ntfs-3g support so NTFS is the best choice.
If Windows was able to read other filesystems the situation would be different ;)

Comment: @Uri you can read and write ntfs out of the box in ubuntu lucid as well as maverick.

Comment: ah, true, it's just that i had to install ntfs-config to actually, write to the NTFS disk

Comment: So assume I don't care about Windows anymore, just Ubuntu and Mac (see edit) which should I then take?

Comment: writing worked also out of the box

Comment: I would go with ext4.

Answer (score 7):

Just saw this in passing. I know its old thread but hey.

What about ExFat? It's OSX/Linux/Windows compatible, but please do check which versions of those its compatible with.

According to Wikipedia it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT

Supported by:
Windows XP and above
OSX 10.6.5 and above
Linux (don't know how far back support goes)

Comment: From the Wikipedia link: "[exFAT support] cannot become an official part of Linux due to the patent encumbered status of the exFAT filesystem". I definitely won't use it.

Comment: exFAT is not jounaled. It means that you have a high chance of damaging your filesystem whenever you disconnect your disk improperly. read: you gonna have to spend time repairing your drive more often than you expect