# Ubuntu USB stick not detected in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystem, usb-drive

I burnt the USB stick with the Ubuntu ISO, and can readily install Ubuntu with that pendrive. But when I plug it in Windows, Windows does not detect it.

Can I make Windows recognize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What filesystem for an external Harddrive (Linux/Mac/Windows)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24425/what-filesystem-for-an-external-harddrive-linux-mac-windows)

Comment: Why should it be detected by Windows? Why would you need it?

Answer (score 0):

you should know, that windows only recognizes
file-formats like
FAT
NTFS
and else DOS-formats

when usb-stick has an unix-filesystem
it happens that it is not readable for windows, unless you use the correct drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd

Its a program/driver to be able to browse ext2/3/4 filesystems from windows.

Source(s):
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9449