# Time a USB flash drive formated in NTFS be read in a linux pc

Tags: usb, flash

My home Network is run by Lenox. My wife will give a friend and new USB flash drive, to save a word processing work she is doing for her. Her friend has a Windows PC therefore the ubs flash drive,  will be formatted  to NTFS. Later when my wife brings back that USB flash drive, would she be able to read it in her Linux laptop? Or should I format this flash drive to a Linux file system? But then a friend with a Windows PC will not be able to do anything. What is the best way to walk around this issue.

AAV

Comment: NTFS read and write support are currently supported in Ubuntu out-the-box. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Who/what is "Lenox"?

Comment: What does your home network have to do with this?

Comment: NTFS read/write is supported in LInux, and has been for ***years***.  NTFS drives work fine.  However, your core question is extremely unclear, and it is not clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What filesystem for an external Harddrive (Linux/Mac/Windows)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24425/what-filesystem-for-an-external-harddrive-linux-mac-windows)

Comment: Why NTFS? If you format in FAT32 even Mac users will be able to read the drive.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount a NTFS filesystem in Linux without problems. 
Just insert the USB into your computer, and the disk will be available in the left pane of the file manager (Files / Nautilus).