# Which filesystem should I use?

Tags: filesystem, hard-drive, gparted

I recently formatted my drive and now it appears as unallocated space in gparted. I want to use the drive for all my files, steam and game installation, to keep my SSD as empty as possible. What filesystem type should I use?

Comment: The most common option is `ext4`. Unless you want your files to be accessible in Windows, you should use ext4.

Comment: This is actually a case of amnesia. I was going to recommend the answer in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19796/filesystem-types-for-partitions since it will server to help you better understand most filesystems... and then I saw that I wrote it lol. Amnesia FTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan on sharing this drive with Windows, then `ext4` will be the best option.

But, in case you have plans on dual-booting with Windows, then it is better to format the drive as `ntfs`, as this is accessible by both Ubuntu and Windows. But, be aware that file permissions may not work properly in an `ntfs` File System .

Comment: @Atladica Considering that you have accepted the answer please consider upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific needs for the drive? If you don't have a specific need you know about, use [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). It's modern, uses extents and has journaling. It's also a descendant of ext2 and ext3, which are relatively well tested. I personally used Reiser4 a lot, but not since it stopped being installed by default by distributions. My answer “use ext4” might sound boring, but many of the exciting filesystems out there are generally less tested and gains (without a specific need) are questionable.