# Need help creating partition for new 2.5 inch drive, new user to ubuntu

Tags: ssd

Installed new 2.5 inch ssd, in disks app in kubuntu says when I am trying to create partition and then format gives 4 options

1. internal disk use for linux systems only (ext4) -
   if I select this one that does that mean I can never change it to windows in the future
2. for use with Windows NTFS
3. for uses for all systems and devices FAT
4. other

I am new to ubuntu and do not know what to select from here to setup this ssd.

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: And what is the purpose of the new partition? Do you want to access the partition only from Kubuntu or also from Windows? Are you using dual boot or do you have only Kubuntu as a single boot installed. Is there any need to be able to access the partition from any other operating system?

Comment: I am trying kubuntu for the first time, if I like it, will keep Kubuntu and not go back to windows, but if don't like and have to do go back to windows, I just want to know I can still use this ssd  on windows or it can only use linux.

Comment: You should probably use NTFS since it's usable by Kubuntu and Windows. In a single boot (only Kubuntu) ext4 would be the better choice. You can always reformat partitions but if you want to keep data you need to backup first, conversion from NTFS to ext4 or vice versa without dataloss is not possible. [Related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/226888/590937).

Comment: I am only using this ssd for games, music and videos, not worried about data loss, since I have copies of if on other computers and USB flash drives.